# Error in Displaying the content of a txt file through Django

Tags: python, django

[This is the text file I want to project in the browser screen.

The second one is the views file which has the function.
[path('ShowFile', views.ShowFile, name ='ShowFile') in the last picture in the urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liBpU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a function like this, substituting the path as needed.

```
def ShowFile(request):
    f = open("C:\\Users\\Soumyaranjan\\PycharmProjects\\Textutils\\textutils\\textutils\\one.txt", "r")
    content = f.readlines()
    return HttpResponse(content)
```